# I want a function like kafka client_id in redis pubsub

Tags: python, redis, apache-kafka

Does redis not have a feature like kafka client_id?

pub.py

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host=host, port=port, db=0)
channel = r.pubsub()

for i in range(10):
    print(r.publish("test", i))

print('end')
```

sub1.py

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host=host, port=port, db=0)

p = r.pubsub()
p.subscribe('test')

# while True:
#     message = p.get_message()
#     if message:
#         print("Subscriber: %s" % message['data'])

for z in p.listen():
    print(z)
```

sub2.py

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host=host, port=port, db=0)

p = r.pubsub()
p.subscribe('test')

# while True:
#     message = p.get_message()
#     if message:
#         print("Subscriber: %s" % message['data'])

for z in p.listen():
    print(z)
```

sub1.py result is

```
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'0'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'1'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'2'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'3'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'4'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'5'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'6'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'7'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'8'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'9'}
```

sub2.py result is

```
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'0'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'1'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'2'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'3'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'4'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'5'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'6'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'7'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'8'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'9'}
```

I don't want to read rows subscribed by other subscribers
It's like kafka's client_id.

I want sub1.py result is

```
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'0'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'2'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'4'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'6'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'8'}
```

I want sub2.py result is

```
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'1'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'3'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'5'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'7'}
{'type': 'message', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'test', 'data': b'9'}
```

I do not want to read rows subscribed by other subscribers.
help Me..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [redis-streams](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro) and their "Consumer groups" feature.